# Get names of all friends from Twitter API

Tags: android, twitter

I want to get names of all friends in efficient way within the API limit of Twitter. I know I can use this method:

```
IDs ids = twitter.getFriendsIDs(cursor);
```

But this method only gives the ids and I need to iterate on this list, which is not efficient at all and will exceed the API call limit.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is one of these API calls:

- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/list

Your Twitter-API Client should have methods for these.